# Spacing around brackets in slanted or italics

Tags: spacing, brackets

From time to time I use brackets as an equivalent of *respectively*, like in the following sentence:

```
A semigroup [monoid, group] $S$ is commutative if, for all $x, y \in S$, $xy = yx$.
```

Now, I would like to be able to write the same sentence in *italics* or *slanted*, while keeping the brackets in roman (or in math mode). I tried something like

```
\textit{$[$test$]$}
```

but it does not produce a nice result, because the second bracket is to close from the words in italics. Next I tried

```
\begin{proposition}     
 Let $M$ be a semigroup $[$monoid, group$\\,]$...  
\end{proposition}
```

which produces a better result, but is still far from being optimal.

So, is there a way to get the appropriate spacing around the brackets?

Comment: You might be interested in @cgnieder's package [`embrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/embrac), which (semi-)automatically handles upright parenthesis in italic text and therefore redefines `\textit` and `\emph`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The brackets are textual punctuation not math symbols so `$[$` is not what you want, I think you want `\textup{[}` The `\text...` commands should automatically handle insertion of italic correction space when switching between slanted and upright styles.